# How to dynamically import_module from a relative path with python importlib

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

My folder structure looks like:

```
__init__.py
core/
    fields.py
    managers.py
    models.py
    __init__.py
models/
    products.py
    suppliers.py
    __init__.py
```

From class A in `fields.py` I'm trying to load class Supplier using `importlib.load_module` from which is defined in products.py or suppliers.py.  This is needed to populate some configurations in order to generate some sql.

The approach below generates `TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '..models.suppliers.Supplier''`. I'm not sure how to define the package, as this isn't an installed package.

```
import importlib

model_name = "Supplier"
path = f"...models.{model_name.lower()}s.{model_name}"
model = importlib.import_module(path)
```

To try and resolve this I've tried out various combination of something like below to no avail.  Error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '.core'` or `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '.models'` depending on the combination of .. I'm using.

```
import importlib

model_name = "Supplier"
path = f"...models.{model_name.lower()}s.{model_name}"
model = importlib.import_module(path, package=".core.fields")
```

```
path = f"{model_name.lower()}s"
model = importlib.import_module(path, package="..models")
```

Doesnt work either - but plainly importing `from ..models import Supplier` does.

I've also tried to get python to use the absolute path.  But by using this approach, the error becomes: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` (Referring to the imports in suppliers.py).

In such case it seems to fail on the relative imports used in suppliers.py.  See below example.

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
from pathlib import Path
import os

model_name = "Supplier"
parent_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
module_path = os.path.join(parent_path, 'models', f'{model_name.lower()}s.py')
Model = getattr(SourceFileLoader(model, module_path).load_module(), model_name)
```

EDIT: For completeness, throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '.'`. So also a no go.

```
model = __import__(f"..models.{model.lower()}.{model}")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What does this have to do with dynamic programming? Have you read the definition of that term?

Comment: is your project correctly configured as a package? (i.e. : the folder containing the toplevel `__init__.py` should be itself in a folder in sys.path, or there should be an appropriate editable-install ? 

If so, it is a matter of manipulating the string to get to the dotted name of the .py file you want, and use `importlib.import_module`, as in `importmodule('myproject.models.suppliers') `. If not, we are facing a XY problem - you need to configure your package to be installable (and for greater confort, and editable install)

Comment: Actually it has been structured in that way, but not installed as such.  I wanted to make sure to make the package with relative imports before installing it.  From your response I take it, that's no the ideal approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more reading, turn out à solution was staring me right in the face.

Instead of trying to do funny things with importlib you can use `getattr`

```
def find_my_class(class_name):
    from .. import models as configuration_models

    module = getattr(configuration_models, f"{class_name.lower()}s")
    return getattr(module, class_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the recipe in the docs about how to load a module given its file path:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly

```
...
import importlib

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[module_name] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

---

Without using pathlib:

(I am keeping this because the examples of filename manipulation and dir handling may still be needed, even when following the recipe above)

Indeed, the correct way to import a file given a file-path in Python is complicated. Without searching for another recipe, here is an approach
that temporarily patches sys.path, and calls plain `__import__` to get the file from the specified dir

(Path to the Python file should be given with filesystem notation: `/` separators, not `.`. This code will ignore file extensions, though)

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def importpath(path):
    strpath = str(path)
    if not strpath.startswith("/"):
        parent_path = Path(sys._getframe().f_globals.get("__file__", ".")).parent
        path = parent_path / path
    else:
        path = Path(path)
    try:
        sys.path.insert(0, str(path.parent))
        module = __import__(path.stem)
    finally:
        sys.path.pop(0)
    return module
```

However, this code will import the given file as a sole Python module with not knowledge of what package it should be in. That means that if there are any relative imports inside that module, they will fail.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately as you already mentioned this makes the relative imports in the target-path fail.

Comment: nice - I found the oficial way of import a file given the filename with importlib now - added above

Comment: Cool solution. I missed that one indeed.  However, the relative imports in suppliers.py are also failing.