# import_module on relative path difference between python 3.5 and 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to implement a plugin system in Python.
Each plugin exposes exactly the same function and I want to call one or another, for instance with a simple Id.
For instance, the plugins can be image loader, each plugin handling a different format (*jpeg*,*bmp*,...).
Plugins are all inside a special directory tree and I try to import them with *relative* syntax.

My issue is that Python 3.5 and Python 3.7 seem to behave differently.

Here is my directory tree

```
root_dir
|
--main.py
|
--plugin_mod1
|   |
|   --extend.py
...
|
--plugin_modN
|   |
|   --extend.py
...
```

here is my "load plugins" function (in `main.py`)

```py
# loads plugins with all the same interface
def LoadPlugin():

    global root_dir
    Extensions = glob.glob(root_dir+'/plugin_*')
    # ExtMods will store the retrieved module
    ExtMods = {}
    sys.path.insert(0, root_dir)
    for Ext in Extensions:
        if os.path.exists(Ext+'/extend.py'):
        
            # Python 3.7+
            # tmp = importlib.import_module(
            #     '.extend', os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(Ext)))
            
            # Python 3.5
            sys.path.insert(0, Ext)
            tmp = importlib.import_module('extend')
            
            # bind some id to the found module
            ExtMods[tmp.PluginId()] = tmp

    return ExtMods
```

The mechanism is used like this in `main.py`

```py
...
#loading all plugins found in root_dir
PluginManager = LoadPlugin()
...
# run DoSomething for plugin <some ID>
PlunginManager[<some ID>].DoSomething()
...
```

If I use the code commented as `Python 3.7+` with `Python 3.7` (on windows), I'm getting the expected result.
If I use the code commented as `Python 3.7+` with `Python 3.5` (on ubuntu), I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<...>/main.py", line <xxx>, in <module>
    PluginManager = LoadPlugin()
  File "<...>/main.py", line <xxx>, in LoadPlugin
    '.extend', os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(Ext)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 981, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 931, in _sanity_check
SystemError: Parent module 'plugin_mod1' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I looked the suggested post [How to dynamically import_module from a relative path with python importlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395188/how-to-dynamically-import-module-from-a-relative-path-with-python-importlib) but I failed to understand how it can apply to my situation.

Thus my questions are:

1. Why is there a difference between the two python versions (I
   failed to find an explanation in python documentation).
2. what would be the correct way to achieve my expected result with the same
   code on different python version (at least from 3.5)?
3. is there a way to avoid the `sys.path.insert(0, <something>)` (especially
   in the 3.5 version that implies, now, to add each plugin path, even
   if temporarily)?

Comment: For 3.7 vs 3.5 - are you sure it's not Windows vs Linux here?

Comment: perhaps, at this time I have no easy way to test. The issue is occurring on python3.5 / ubuntu 16

Comment: @declension python3.8/ubuntu20 seems OK. So I'm more inclined to think it's a python version issue

Comment: [PEP 366](https://peps.python.org/pep-0366/) is it possible that this modification in python 3.6 explains the difference in behavior? The notion of python package name as mentioned in python documentation is quite unclear for me...