# importlib.import_module loading the wrong module in custom plugin system

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to implement a plugin system in Python.
Each plugin exposes exactly the same function and I want to call one or another, for instance with a simple Id.
For instance, the plugins can be image loader, each plugin handling a different format (*jpeg*,*bmp*,...).
Plugins are all inside a special directory tree and I try to import them with *relative* syntax.

My issue is that, as soon as I've got more than one plugin, my plugin loader always loads the same one.

Here is my directory tree

```
root_dir
|
--main.py
|
--plugin_mod1
|   |
|   --extend.py
...
|
--plugin_modN
|   |
|   --extend.py
...
```

here is my "load plugins" function (in `main.py`)

```py
# loads plugins with all the same interface
def LoadPlugin():

    global root_dir
    Extensions = glob.glob(root_dir+'/plugin_*')
    # ExtMods will store the retrieved module
    ExtMods = {}
    sys.path.insert(0, root_dir)
    for Ext in Extensions:
        if os.path.exists(Ext+'/extend.py'):
        
            sys.path.insert(0, Ext)
            tmp = importlib.import_module('extend')
            
            # bind some id to the found module
            ExtMods[tmp.PluginId()] = tmp
            # on second iteration, tmp is still imported from first plugin

            # same undesired behavior if following line is uncommented
            # sys.path.remove(Ext)

    return ExtMods
```

The mechanism is used like this in `main.py`

```py
...
#loading all plugins found in root_dir
PluginManager = LoadPlugin()
...
# run DoSomething for plugin <some ID>
PlunginManager[<some ID>].DoSomething()
...
```

The python 3.5 solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/21691539) works but why doesn't my implementation (`import_module` always loading the same one)?

Optional: is there a better design to manage plugin with python?

NB: I also encountered [issues with respect to python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412385/import-module-on-relative-path-difference-between-python-3-5-and-3-7) but couldn't find a definitive answer.
Ideally the solution should work with Python 3 or more, whatever the minor version.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Python3.5? When using `spec_from_file_location` what is the module name and filepath you use?

Comment: for testing I have currently access to a python 3.7(.6) but I have to support also older installation such as 3.5 (yet I don't have access to one at this time). Following question snippet, I tried spec_from_file_location('extend',Ext) and spec_from_file_location('extend.py',Ext). I just see that, I must had the python script name to the path. I test and come back.

Comment: My bad, it seems to work with full path, including the ```.py```. I'll run some additional tests and may rephrase the question, just to know why proposed code does not work.

Comment: Edit made to change question focus.

Comment: I think the problem with your implementation is that once you load the first one, that plugin will be available on path and loaded. (Speculation ahead) Since you're trying to import a module with the same name, a module that is already loaded, python figures there's no point, even if another module is ahead in path.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932069/building-a-minimal-plugin-architecture-in-python) is _a bit_ old, but give it a try. But if you port it to newer python using importlib it seems like you would get something similar to `find_spec`

Comment: @Ftagliacarne Thx, I'll give it a try.